# Are "come round" and "visit" interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice

> Some friends will come round for dinner.
>
> Some friends will visit for dinner.
>
> Some friends will visit me.

These are OK, but "some friends will come round me" isn't OK.

The answer is simple, but it needs some thought.

Comment: Why are you telling us the answer is simple? This isn't a trivia site where you ask a question and wait until someone gives the answer you think is correct.

Comment: Perhaps someone will prove me wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The two have very similar meanings but there *are* different connotations. Someone coming "around" subtlety implies that they will be coming around again or have been here in the past. It also implies a much less formal happening as if there is little reason to make a fuss about the event.

> The watchman will be coming around about 6.
>
> The watchman will be visiting about 6.

In addition to this, "around" or "round" have other meanings that separate them from "visit." Robusto's example is good. Others are:

> The watchman will be coming around 6.
>
> The watchman will be coming around the corner.

Answer (score 0):

The expressions doesn't have the exact same meaning always, but in this case they are interchangeable.

When you use *visit*, that the friends are visiting you is implied:

> Some friends will visit [me] for dinner.

You can replace *visit me* with *come around*:

> Some friends will come around.

However, you can't use *come around* instead of *visit me* for all places:

> Some friends will visit me in prison.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: only thing I can see is that "friends will come around" has a second meaning, which may not be clear.

Comment: @jgbelacqua: If you mean *come around* in the sense of changing ones opinion, that would be a possible interpretation of the sentence, but then the context would be different.

Comment: true.  Just trying to fathom why someone would down-vote this.

Answer (score 0):

*Round* is a "chiefly British" [NOAD] variant of *around*. It can be substituted freely.

> *Come, gather round me, and I'll tell you.* — W. S. Gilbert, "A Wandering Minstrel I" from *The Mikado*

You can see that this quote exactly parallels your "Some friends will come round me," so I would say from a usage standpoint that it is acceptable, at least in British English.

Comment: I think that the simple answer is that 'come around' is used for a place and 'visit' is used for people and places.

Comment: I just gave you an example by one of the cleverest lyricists of his time in which *round* is used with a person as its object. Surely this is evidence that your assertion doesn't hold water.

Comment: @nicholas ainsworth: I think you've got your head stuck in one meaning, while @Robusto's example has a somewhat different meaning.  "Some friends will get into close physical proximity with me" and "Some friends will come to my house" are what we're playing with here.

Comment: -1. Misleadning. While the expression might be usable, it would no longer have the same meaning.

Comment: +1 The question outright states that this expression isn't OK, when it is.

Comment: @Rhodi: No, it's not OK. The title asks if the expressions are interchangeable. If you change the sentence to mean something completely different, they are not interchangeable.